# Проблема табуляции(внутри редактора) в IDLE

Tags: python, idle

В IDLE,при нажатии на клавишу tab,обычно ставится 4 пробела,но иногда 8 пробелов,в опциях IDLE указано,что размер табуляции - 4 пробела,и я не знаю,как это контролировать,например:

1)

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Это привычная табуляция

2)

```
class Example:
        def __init__(self):
                pass
```

А этого варианта хотелось бы избежать

Comment: Я бы сказал, проще вообще не использовать IDLE

Comment: "но иногда 8 пробелов" -- когда? Как это можно воспроизвести?